# Can't open NSStream from XCTest in Swift

Tags: swift, foundation, xctest, nsstream

I am trying to write an XCTest that tests a socket connection. Here is what my connection code roughly looks like:

```
public class MyConnection: NSObject, NSStreamDelegate {
  private let queue = NSOperationQueue()
  private var inputStream: NSInputStream!
  private var outputStream: NSOutputStream!

  public func connect() {
    println("Attempting to connect")
    queue.addOperationWithBlock() {
      var readStream: Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
      var writeStream: Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?
      CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(nil,
                                         "[my ip address]",
                                         8333,
                                         &readStream,
                                         &writeStream);
      if readStream == nil || writeStream == nil {
        println("Connection failed")
        return
      }
      self.inputStream = readStream!.takeUnretainedValue()
      self.outputStream = writeStream!.takeUnretainedValue()
      self.inputStream.delegate = self
      self.outputStream.delegate = self
      self.inputStream.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
      self.outputStream.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
      self.inputStream.open()
      self.outputStream.open()
    }
  }

  // MARK: - NSStreamDelegate

  public func stream(stream: NSStream!, handleEvent event: NSStreamEvent) {
    println("THIS NEVER GETS CALLED!")
    // Notifies delegate that connection opened.
  }
}
```

The XCTestCase I wrote basically just calls the connect() method and waits for a delegate method to be called once the connection succeeds. However, the delegate method is never called. Do I need to do something special for this to work in my test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that this was failing in my unit tests was a red herring. This code doesn't work because of the way NSOperationQueue works. A queue creates and destroys threads on the fly. So I was scheduling my streams on the run loop for a thread that was only short lived. Hence, my callbacks never got called because the run loop was destroyed.

The right solution was to create an NSThread directly and use the run loop from that thread instead of trying to use a queue.

Comment: so how to resolve this problem, could you make a sample code please?